# Can not connect to Redis inside MongoClient.connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redis

I'm having trouble to connect Redis inside MongoClient.connect.

Although both separately works, inside mongo s callback somehow Redis does not connect.

My file structure is like this:

mongoUtil.js:

```
const chalk       = require( 'chalk' )
const MongoClient = require( 'mongodb' ).MongoClient
const appConfig   = require( '../config/appConfig' )

let _db

module.exports = {

 connectToServer: callback => {
   MongoClient.connect(
     appConfig.MONGO_URL,
     { promiseLibrary: Promise },
     ( err, db ) => {
       _db = db;
       console.log( chalk.blue('Connected to MongoDB') )
       callback( err )
     }
   )
 },

 getDb: function() {
  return _db;
 }
}
```

redisUtil.js:

```
const chalk       = require( 'chalk' )
const redis       = require('redis')

let client        = redis.createClient()

module.exports = {

  connectToServer : callback => {
    client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log( chalk.red('Connected to Redis') )
    callback()
   } )
},

  getDb: function() {
    return client;
  }
}
```

server.js: **this does not work**

```
const mongoUtil     = require( './lib/mongoUtil' )
const redisUtil     = require( './lib/redisUtil' )

mongoUtil.connectToServer( err => {

  redisUtil.connectToServer( () => {
    // some server code
  })

})
```

server.js: **this works**

```
const mongoUtil     = require( './lib/mongoUtil' )
const redisUtil     = require( './lib/redisUtil' )

redisUtil.connectToServer( () => {
  // some server code
})    

mongoUtil.connectToServer( err => {

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a timing issue. By the time you call `redisUtil.connectToServer` the connection to Redis will already have been established, so the `connect` event won't fire. Calling `redis.createClient()` will attempt to connect straight away, it won't wait for you to register the `connect` event listener.

Off the top of my head, something like this should work:

```
connectToServer: callback => {
    if (client.connected) {
        console.log(chalk.red('Already connected to Redis'));
        callback();
    }
    else {
        client.on('connect', () => {
            console.log(chalk.red('Connected to Redis'));
            callback();
        }
    }
)
```

I'm not sure whether this will work if the `client` is in the process of reconnecting. It's also quite misleading having a function called `connectToServer` when it isn't responsible for kicking off the connection. You might want to consider tweaking your code so that `createClient` is called inside `connectToServer`, more like how you have it with Mongo.

Comment: If 'let client        = redis.createClient()' automatically attempts to connect to db, what you are saying should be true. I did not consider this, but makes perfect sense. I will test your solution. Thanks